# jQuery .post doesn't return data in done and fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm having trouble making a jQuery AJAX request and getting the data back in the .done and .fail methods. Here is the code the calls the AJAX-requesting code:

```
async function doSomething(){
    const addressValid = await isAddressValid(form.address1.value, form.address2.value, form.city.value, form.state.value, form.zip.value);
    if(!addressValid) return
}
```

And here's the request code:

```
export default (address1, address2, city, state, zip) => {
    console.log(`Checking address`);
    return $.post('/api/validate', {
            address1,
            address2,
            city,
            state,
            zip
        })
        .done(function(data, status, xhr){
            // Address is valid
            return true;
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            // Address is invalid or API is down, etc
            return false;
        });
}
```

My problem is that the return statements in the .done() and .fail() do not work. After isAddressValid(), addressValid is either 'OK' if the address is good, or just nothing. There's multiple problems with this - the first is that it disregards my `return true;` entirely. The second is that when the address is invalid, the server returns a 400, and that returns nothing at all to addressValid.

Per https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/:

> As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of
>   the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR,"
>   returned by $.get() implements the Promise interface, giving it all
>   the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred
>   object for more information).

So it seems like what I'm doing should work. I am thinking the promise will be resolved with my boolean return values, but it's not. I've done this in the past with promises (not jQuery). For example, use request-promise to request something, return the response and store it in a variable.

Would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log('true')` instead of trying to return it?

Comment: @Spartacus sorry, forgot to mention that -- the .done() and .fail() DO execute. So to your question, when I do `console.log('true');`, I see `true` in the console

Comment: @CBroe I thought this looked like a duplicate too but it is not. OP is doing everything right in that regard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is this is due to jQuery's *promise-like* jqXHR object.

The `await` keyword expects a promise and will use the standard `then` (and maybe `catch`) methods to determine the result.

Try this instead

```
return $.post(...).then(() => true, () => false)
```

---

Alternatively, use something other than jQuery that returns actual `Promise` instances. Even the native `fetch` API may be better suited.

Comment: AHH, that did it. It looks like `.then()` is taking success and error callbacks per https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/? Thank you btw @Phil